# Initializing Code-First entities from existing database using EntityFramework 6.1.1 in MVC5.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have EF6.1.1 installed in a MVC5.2 project (using VS2013). I successfully used code-first to generate the database and I also wrote an initializer with dummy data for testing. For production, I need to load the initial data from an older database on a different server. The table structures are similar but not identical, and the tables have the same names in both databases; I can't use the same models for both.

In addition to the code-first context I have declared a context for the older database, but I don't know what to do with it. Ideally, I would like to pull entities from the old database, then copy field-wise to new entities. If that isn't possible, I'd like to pull rows of old data and somehow populate new entities with the data.

Here is my context declaration for the code-first database:

```
namespace ITDAccounting.DAL
{
    public class ITDAccountingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
     }
}
```

And my context for the old database:

```
namespace ITDAccounting.DAL
{
    public class BillableUnitsContext : DbContext
    {
// 
    }
}
```

And some of my initializer code. Obviously, this is bogus data; I want to replace this with code that pulls legit entries from the existing database:

```
namespace ITDAccounting.DAL
{
    public class ITDAccountingInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ITDAccountingContext>
    {
        BillableUnitsContext existingDataContext = new BillableUnitsContext();

        protected override void Seed(ITDAccountingContext context)
        {    
            var employees = new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee{EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-01"),Status="A", Number="999001", Wages=96000.00M, Benefits=25000.00M,  Communications=0.0M, Tools=60.0M, TradeMemberships=0.0M, Training=160.0M}
                ,new Employee{EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-02"),Status="A", Number="999002", Wages=86000.00M, Benefits=25001.00M,  Communications=300.0M, Tools=50.0M, TradeMemberships=10.0M, Training=150.0M}
                ,new Employee{EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-03"),Status="A", Number="999003", Wages=76000.00M, Benefits=25002.00M,  Communications=40.0M, Tools=40.0M, TradeMemberships=10.0M, Training=140.0M}
                ,new Employee{EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-04"),Status="A", Number="999004", Wages=66000.00M, Benefits=25003.00M,  Communications=50.0M, Tools=30.0M, TradeMemberships=10.0M, Training=130.0M}
                ,new Employee{EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-05"),Status="A", Number="999005", Wages=56000.00M, Benefits=25004.00M,  Communications=60.0M, Tools=20.0M, TradeMemberships=10.0M, Training=120.0M}
                ,new Employee{EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-06"),Status="A", Number="999006", Wages=46000.00M, Benefits=25005.00M,  Communications=750.0M, Tools=10.0M, TradeMemberships=10.0M, Training=110.0M}
             };
        employees.ForEach(e => context.Employees.Add(e));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var departments = new List<Department>
        {
            new Department{ EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-01"), Status="A", Name="Tacos", Number="999765", Fund="7777", BalanceSheetAccount="44445555", RevenueAccount="11113434"}
            ,new Department{ EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-02"), Status="A", Name="Burritos", Number="999234", Fund="9080", BalanceSheetAccount="44441111", RevenueAccount="11114545"}
            ,new Department{ EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-31"), Status="A", Name="BirthdayCake", Number="998754", Fund="1040", BalanceSheetAccount="44442222", RevenueAccount="11116466"}
            ,new Department{ EffDate=DateTime.Parse("2014-07-04"), Status="A", Name="Diet Creme Soda", Number="991234", Fund="0012", BalanceSheetAccount="44443333", RevenueAccount="11112512"}

        };
        departments.ForEach(d => context.Departments.Add(d));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    protected override void Seed(ITDAccountingContext context)
    {
        using (BillableUnitsContext existingDataContext = new BillableUnitsContext())
        {
            var newEmployeeRecords = new List<Employee>();
            foreach (var oldDbEmployee in existingDataContext.Employees.where(e=>MeetsYourSelectionCriteria(e)) 
            {
                newEmployeeRecords.Add(
                    new Employee 
                    {
                        Name = oldDbEmployee.Name, 
                        Rank = oldDbEmployee.Rank, 
                        SerialNo=oldDbEmployee.SerialNo
                    });   
            }

            //similar stuff for departments

        }
        context.Employees.AddRange(newEmployeeRecords);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: In light, of Erik's excellent point I should clarify that the above approach is only intended to answer the direct question asked and assumes that the number of entries being moved from the old database are relatively small (as Erik points out - using the above code they would all need to be stored in memory at once! Whilst you could do them in batches freeing up memory each time, the more records you have the messier and slower this will inevitably become)

Comment: Thanks, Stewart, that's precisely what I needed. I now have to figure out how to connect the existingDataContext to the existing database (I'm guessing a database-first exercise). The problem: both models contain the same table names; I'm not sure how to move the existingDataContext to a new namespace. Google University, here I come!

Comment: My pleasure - db first is easy-enough for something like this. just add a new Entity Data Model & follow the wizard to point it at the tables you need. It guides you through everything pretty good and even gives you a nice map of your existing db for free. Happy Hunting.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, how you do this depends on many factors.  EF is generally not a good choice for ETL work.  Each row you insert creates a larger and larger memory footprint in the local data cache, and it takes a very long time.  EF is not designed for bulk operations.

You should probably use something like SSIS, or other dedicated ETL tools.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I'll explore SSIS and look for other ETL tools to see if any could be more effective. I'm not looking at a ton of data, though; most of my tables contain less than 1000 rows, and none have more than 10k.